# Postgresql constraint exclusion

Tags: postgresql

I have a huge table named audittrailreference so I partitioned it on the basis of date (1 table for a day).

The table has two date fields (intime & outtime)

for any row either of them could be null but not both or it might be  possible that both of them may carry date.

Now I need to put the constraint exclusion to increase the performance of my queries.

my table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.auditrtailreference
(
    event smallint,
    innodeid character varying(80),
    innodename character varying(80),
    sourceid character varying(300),
    intime timestamp without time zone,
    outnodeid character varying(80),
    outnodename character varying(80),
    destinationid character varying(300),
    outtime timestamp without time zone,
    bytes integer,
    cdrs integer,
    noofsubfilesinfile integer,
    recordsequencenumberlist character varying(1000),
    partial_cdrs integer,
    duplicate_cdrs integer,
    discarded_cdrs integer,
    created_cdrs integer,
    corrupted_cdrs integer,
    created_files integer,
    duplicate_files integer,
    corrupted_files integer,
    partial_files integer,
    discarded_files integer,
    empty_files integer
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE myschema.auditrtailreference
    OWNER TO erix;

-- Trigger: auditrtailreference_trigger on myschema.auditrtailreference

-- DROP TRIGGER auditrtailreference_trigger ON myschema.auditrtailreference;

CREATE TRIGGER auditrtailreference_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON myschema.auditrtailreference
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE myschema.auditrtailreference_partition_function();
```

Comment: I want to put the constraint exclusion on intime & outtime

Comment: Have you partitioned the table by intime or outtime date? Can the intime and outtime be two different dates?

Comment: Hello Simo, I have partitioned on basis of both. Since in some rows there is only intime & outtime is NULL whereas in some other rows intime is NULL & outtime has value :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it on my own brothers

Thanks to all for your time

```
CONSTRAINT "auditrtailreference_2014-10-02_intime_check" CHECK (intime >= '2014-10-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND intime < '2014-10-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone OR intime IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT "auditrtailreference_2014-10-02_outtime_check" CHECK (outtime >= '2014-10-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND outtime < '2014-10-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone OR outtime IS NULL)
```

Comment: If the intime and outtime are on the same date then it is sufficient to test for one of them and the other is redundant. If they are not on the same date then you have multiple partitions per one intime date - maybe that is expected...